# Pagination in Jsp many pages

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I have many pages so i want to display only 10 then "..." then the last 10.

This is the table with data:

```
<table class="CSSTableGenerator" border=1px; cellspacing="1">
<tr>
    <th>Vehicle Id</th>
    <th>BaseVehicle Id</th>
    <th>Submodel Id</th>
    <th>Region Id</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="listElement" items="${vehicleIds}">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${listElement.vehicleId}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${listElement.baseVehicleId}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${listElement.submodelId}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${listElement.regionId}" /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

This is the bottom table:

```
<table class="SimpleTable">
<tr>
    <c:forEach begin="1" end="${noOfPages}" var="i">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${currentPage eq i}">
                <td>${i}</td>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <td><a
                    href="adminCsv.do?csvs=${idCsv }&method=View_Data&page=${i}">${i}</a></td>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
</tr>
```

Suggestions please?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what is not working. If you're interested in existing solutions, there are some open source libraries like [displaytag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/) that help with this.

Comment: you can create custom tag library or can use http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/

Comment: I resolved, sorry if my question was not explicit enough